# Formula of what substance is shown in the clip Disappointed by Electronic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, identification

I'd like to know the substance (if any) the model of which is shown in the clip [Disappointed by Electronic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disappointed_(Electronic_song)).
The following screenshot is taken from the video [electronicofficial —
Electronic - Disappointed (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUTJCIPsWwE):

[image]

Comment: Just a cartoon.

Comment: Disappointed, @AChem, thought that maybe they were trying to convey some hidden meaning )

Comment: Blue is an oxygen atom; red is a carbon atom; green is a hydrogen atom. It is a cyclohexane ring where 4 carbon atoms are connected to 1 H and 1 OH. The two remaining carbon atoms are difficult to understand. One carbon atom is not connected to any atom out of the ring.(which is absurd). And the last carbon atom is connected to a group looking like -OH-OH (which is also absurd).

Comment: Thanks, @Maurice, oh,oh may be just an encoding for a sad interjection ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a structure search within CCDC 2016 database (should be good enough for the 1992 video) for the connectivity graph with complete disregard of the used color scheme:

[image: CCDC ConQuest 2016 structure search query]

Here, `X` stands for *any* atom of the periodic table and `T1` to `T4` refer to the number of bonded atoms for each `X`.

The only molecule that comes up is [glucose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose) alongsode with related aldohexose stereoisomers (allose, galactose, mannose, talopyranose, talose and more).
I wouldn't try to pick the correct stereoisomer since the structure is being unrealistically bent and mirrored virtually all the time.
I tried my best to align the real glucose structure (for example, [CCDC 1500503](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=1500503&DatabaseToSearch=Published)) to match the one from your screenshot:

[image]

I'm fairly certain the color code for atoms is meaningless and was an arbitrary artistic choice.
There are several atoms that give this away (labeled with yellow arrows).

The green color for terminal atoms holds pretty well for hydrogen atoms, but the single red bridging atom having only two neighbors cannot be assigned for carbon (this would imply linearity of $\ce{C=C=C}$ fragment).
The two blue atoms connected with each other have vastly different environments and hardly can be assigned to a meaningful functional group (at least in organic chemistry).